# Javascript Blob.slice method cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, blob, slice

Doing a bit of learning about the [Blob](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#blob) type with File access in HTML5 capable browsers and I discovered that Chrome doesn't use `Blob.slice()` but `Blob.webkitSlice()`.

Does anyone know if there is a method for this that is accepted cross-browser yet or do I need to write my own?

If I need to write my own, can anyone guide me to where this method is defined in Firefox and IE9? (and probably Opera too)

**EDIT**
Found the [Firefox definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob) and it appears that it used to use `slice()` but now uses `mozSlice()`.
So that leaves Opera and IE9+

Comment: File api is not supported in IE9, http://caniuse.com/#search=blob

Comment: I want to give you +100 points just for that link to caniuse.com.  Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epascarello answered it above in the comments:

> File api is not supported in IE9, [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=blob)

Comment: As a side note, `slice` has been unprefixed in Chrome in the meantime.